# Using FastBuild with Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have started using FastBuild for distributed building of my projects. I have created a demo project that that has a directory dir and inside that directory I have these files: main.cpp, header.h, header.cpp, Makefile, fbuild.bff.

Makefile contains the following code:

output: main.o h1.o

```
    g++ main.o h1.o -o output
```

main.o: main.cpp

```
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

h1.o: h1.cpp h1.h

```
    g++ -c h1.cpp
```

clean:

```
    rm *.o output
```

What I want to do is that I want to go into the directory and run FBuild.exe in the command prompt. I want FastBuild to then follow the configurations written into the Makefile and execute accordingly. How should I configure fbuild.bff in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I have recieved the confirmation from the FastBuild team. It seems we cannot usefully integrate Makefile with FastBuild.

Comment: This can be found [here](https://github.com/fastbuild/fastbuild/issues/931). TL;DR: FastBuild doesn't understand makefiles; it is a replacement for make. It could invoke make, but then you wouldn't benefit from FastBuild's features (distributed compilation, caching etc).